How to filter a multi-valued taxonomy field with context if "Allow multiple" is unavailable?
How can I create a filter in Filter criteria for a multi-valued field (field_term_target_id) in Views so that it correctly processes multiple values? It is important that the filter takes into account the current context using a relationship with the taxonomy term (term_node_tid). For example, if I am ALREADY on a term page from the same taxonomy dictionary, say /my-views/term-name%
Also, when enabling the Allow multiple values ​​option in Context, Drupal returns an error Attempt to assign property "type" on null in ManyToOneHelper->ensureMyTable()
And the Allow multiple values ​​option is only available for context filters, not for regular filters. What are the implementation options?
Views works with the field_term_target_id dictionary and one term of this dictionary is initially specified in the URL (/my-views/term-name%). i.e. when you click on an open filter, the URL with the first term is saved. This is done in order to get the desired type of link and create taxonomy pages with these URLs.
